# Java: Map entry Boolean value throws an error

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a Map with a `GregorianCalendar` key and `Boolean` value. The for loop. The `Map.Entry<...>` is underlined and it says

```
Incompatible types.
Required: Object
Found: Entry<java.util.GregorianCalendar, java.lang.Boolean>
```

My code is:

```
public static int getDay(GregorianCalendar day) {
    Map days = getDays();

    for (Map.Entry<GregorianCalendar, Boolean> entry : days.entrySet())
    {

    }

    return -1;
}
```

If someone knows what I'm doing wrong please help me. Really appreciate.

Comment: **Use [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html)**, not `GregorianCalendar`. The terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've defined `days` as a raw `Map` instead of defining its generics:

```
Map<GregorianCalendar, Boolean> days = getDays();
```